# How to Navigate without context in flutter?

Tags: flutter, navigation, android-context

I ended up with using a static function but I need to do navigation and It gave me an error that no getter was found for context so I looked for a solution and found the GET package but when I tried to use it It gave me another error :

```
E/flutter ( 6078): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(166)] 
Unhandled Exception: NoSuchMethodError: The method 'push' was called on null.
```

My code:

```dart
    void main() {
      runApp(MyApp());
      _MyAppState.autologin();
    }
    
    class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
      static autologin() async {
        var userType;
        var store = Firestore.instance;
        var auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
        final FirebaseUser user = await auth.currentUser();
        store.collection('Users').document(user.uid).get().then((value) {
          userType = (value.data)['userType'];
          if (userType == 'Student') {
            Get.to(StudentsPage());
          } else if (userType == 'Teacher') {
          } else if (userType == 'Admin') {}
        });
      }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a navigator key

```
final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
```

Assign it to MaterialApp

```
MaterialApp(
    home: Home(),
    navigatorKey: navigatorKey
),
```

Then push your routes by navigatorKey below

```
navigatorKey.currentState.push(MaterialPageRoute(
    builder: (context) => AnotherPage(),
));
```

or

```
navigatorKey.currentState.pushNamed(routeName);
```

Comment: It gives me that navigatorKey isn't defined as a getter.

Comment: how can we pass multiple paramters and get/use set params on another screen? kindly suggest. Thanks.

Comment: This answer is taken from https://github.com/brianegan/flutter_redux/issues/5#issuecomment-361215074.

Downvoted for not including source.

Comment: getting null on navigatorkey.currentstate when sending firebase push notification and trying to launch product page from main.dart without context. do you have any sulution?

Comment: be sure to add navigatorkey to materialapp

Comment: @M.Evers isnt it possible that i can write the code as well?

Answer (score 0):

This solution is general if you want to navigate or to show Dialog without context using globalKey especially with Bloc or when your logic is separated from your UI part.

Firstly install this package:

Note: I'm using null safety version

```
  get_it: ^7.2.0
```

Then create a separate file for your service locator:

**service_location.dart**

```
    import 'package:get_it/get_it.dart';
    
    GetIt locator = GetIt.instance;
    
    class NavigationService {
      final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey =
          new GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
      Future<dynamic> navigateTo(String routeName) {
        return navigatorKey.currentState!.pushNamed(routeName);
      }
    
      void setupLocator() {
        locator.registerLazySingleton(() => NavigationService());
      }

  void showMyDialog() {
    showDialog(
        context: navigatorKey.currentContext!,
        builder: (context) => Center(
              child: Material(
                color: Colors.transparent,
                child: Text('Hello'),
              ),
            ));
  }
    }
```

on **main.dart:**

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  NavigationService().setupLocator();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
// add navigatorKey for MaterialApp

 MaterialApp(
        navigatorKey: locator<NavigationService>().navigatorKey,
      ),
```

at your business logic file **bloc.dart**
define this inside the bloc class or at whatever class you want to use  navigation inside
Then start to navigate inside any function inside.

```
class Cubit extends Cubit<CubitState> {
  final NavigationService _navigationService = locator<NavigationService>();
  void sampleFunction(){
       _navigationService.navigateTo('/home_screen'); // to navigate
       _navigationService.showMyDialog(); // to show dialog

    }
}
```

Not: I'm using generateRoute for routing.

Comment: I am getting an error while compiling `Invalid constant value.dart(invalid_constant)` in `navigatorKey: locator<NavigationService>().navigatorKey`. Any recommendation?